# 'Android SDK missing' error when trying to install Titanium

Tags: 13.10, android, software-installation, ide

I'm trying to install Titanium on my Ubuntu 13.10.

But I can't setup Android SDK. It always show an Error like `An Android SDK is missing. Titanium requires Android platform: 2.3.3 or above.`

I have already install this SDK version and the releated `Google APIs`. But it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: They are the android-sdk directories: `add-ons`, `build-tools`, `docs`, `extras`, `platforms`, `platform-tools`, `samples`, `SDK Readme.txt`, `sources`, `system-images`, `temp` and `tools`.